# google map api v3 : update rectangle bounds when the shape is dragged or resized

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on google map api v3 using the draw tool. I want the user to be able to :

1. get the rectangle bounds when the shape is complete.
2. update the bounds when the rectangle is dragged or re-seized.

The (1) worked fine but i need some help on (2).
This is the code i used for (1) :

```
 //----------on rectangle complete event
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
         //get the rectangle bounds
         document.getElementById("savedata").value =rectangle.getBounds();     
    //hide draw tool
    drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingControl: false
            });
    //disable draw tool 
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event listener to the rectangle for bounds_changed, capture the new coordinates in that.  Code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "bounds_changed", function() {
   document.getElementById("savedata").value =rectangle.getBounds();
});
```

Here is [an example using the DrawingManager](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) that allows you to draw rectangles, change them and capture the changed value.  The only thing missing from it is the [change event (bounds_changed on the rectangle)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events).